# XCode 9.3 can only remember one account and shows unknown team name

Tags: xcode, keychain

My Xcode has upgraded to Version 9.3, I have more than one Apple account, it works well when I add one more account to Xcode, but only one account is left when reopening Xcode, and the Team field shows "Unknown Name XXX".

This may be caused by Keychain, and I have deleted the corresponding certificates, but the issue is still the same.

[image]

Comment: I'm also having this issue.

Comment: same issue with xcode 10.1..find solutions??