# Account automatically removed from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Few days back I added an account in `Xcode` preferences which succeeded and I was running the app on device. But today when I opened `Xcode`, the account was nowhere to be found. The same happened before as well. At that time I thought there might be some connectivity issue but then I faced it again. Possible reason ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try check and uncheck Automatically manage signing

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya : The screenshot is just for showing that account existed before, since it has an identifier. Issue has nothing to relate with the checkbox. On opening the Teams dropdown, then account was missing.

Comment: yesterday I also  faced this issue, once i shutdown my system and reopen again , the account's automatically deleted ,

Comment: Not sure, might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871277/xcode-9-3-can-only-remember-one-account-and-shows-unknown-team-name

Comment: I also faced same issue with **Xcode 9.3**

Comment: I guess Xcode 9.3 has this issue. Need to report this to Apple.

Comment: I have just reported this bug to Apple on Bug Reporter - https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=40089926

Comment: i have the same issue in xcode 10.1. PI respond if someone find a way out

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik did you find the way out?

Comment: @TheTravloper - I followed the below answer ,its works for me, are you tried.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i tried it but the issues remains same. the below answers have 2 refrences. which one did you actually followed

Comment: @TheTravloper - follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675844/xcode-9-3-session-expires-every-time-i-close-and-re-open-xcode/49822288#49822288

Comment: means to say re - installing xcode might fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Xcode 9 bug, Many user faces this issue.

Xcode 9.3 now uses Keychain Access Groups to store your Apple ID credentials in the keychain.

You can fix this problem by setting a user default. In Terminal, using below command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService -bool NO
```

Ref:

[Accounts disappearing in Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46400744/1597744)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822288/1597744